# Create Pie Chart in R

Tags: r

I would like to create a bar chart in R with how many mens and how many womens vote for green topics.
The percentage of women is 64%
The percentage of men is 36%.
I want the Title "Gender-specific vote for green topics" and the color red for female and blue for male in the pie chart. Could someone please help?

```
slices <- c(36,64)

lbls <- c("male", "female")

pie(slices, labels = lbls, main="gender-specific vote for green topics")
```

Problems with add color blue for men and red for women

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1, y = c(64, 36), Sex = c("Female", "Male")),
       aes(x, y, fill = Sex)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(y, "%")), colour = "white", 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("deepskyblue4", "tomato2")) +
  ggtitle("Gender-specific vote for green topics") +
  theme(title = element_text(size = 16, face = 2, hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```r
slices <- c(36,64)
lbls <- c("male", "female")
```

Let's see what's is behind `pie()`:

```r
?pie()
[...]
Arguments
[...]
col  -- a vector of colors to be used in filling or shading the slices. If missing a set of 6 pastel colours is used, unless density is specified when par("fg") is used.
```

Then just entering a vector of desired colours it gives us:

```r
pie(slices, labels = lbls, col=c("blue", "red"), main="gender-specific vote for green topics")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>